# how to get order/quote getAttributes in magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, attributes, orders, php-5.4

I want to retrieve all the existing magento order attributes. For customer attributes i used `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getAttributes()`, for customer address attributes i used `Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getAttributes()`. Similarly how to get Order all attributes? I tried `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getAttributes()`, but we don't have `getAttributes()` method for `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` .

Please help me on how to get order/quote `getAttributes()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Order model is not a EAV model. What kind of attributes you want to join?

Answer (score 1):

Since 'sales/order' and 'sales/quote' uses flat table and not EAV, then EAV attributes would be the same as the table columns name.

Try

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read'); 
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales/order');
$saleField=$readConnection->describeTable($tableName);

print_r($saleField);
```

Comment: this doesn't include attributes of shipping address, billing address, Payment, Invoice. How to get all attributes related to order?

Comment: Could you explain more on what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: @R.S how to achieve the same in magento2?

Comment: @prasadmaganti please create a new question

Comment: @R.S http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98148/how-to-get-order-attributes-in-magento2 but no help